# How to integrate payoneer payment method using Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, payment, gateway, integrate

I want to integrate the payoneer payment gateway into my site.
I'm new to this API so I need help here.

Comment: may be  Payonner payment gateway has no API.
This they manage on the basis of any other form